# Contentoptions custom drawer navigator does work react navigation 4

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Hi everybody i make a react native and expo app, previously i have a problem with the global data and my fix that use Redux, in this moment i implement redux so :

```js
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  Galeria: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLockMode : 'locked-closed',
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
        <Icon
        type='Entypo'
        name='camera'
        style={{fontSize:20, color : tintColor}}
        />)
      } 
  },
  Modificar : {
    screen: editprofile,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
        <Icon
        type='FontAwesome5'
        name='user-edit'
        style={{fontSize:20, color : tintColor}}
        />)
    }
  }
},
{
  drawerPosition: 'right',
  contentOptions : {
    activeTintColor:'#ffffff',
    inactiveTintColor : '#1f1f1f',
    activeBackgroundColor : '#24d060', 
    inactiveBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    headerMode: 'none'
  },
  contentComponent:({navigation, items, renderIcon, getLabel, onItemPress}) => (
    <Provider store ={createStore(Reducers)}>
    <CustomDrawerContentComponent 
    items={items}
    renderIcon={renderIcon} 
    getLabel={getLabel}
    navigation={navigation}
    onItemPress={onItemPress}/>
    </Provider>
  ),
})
```

the problem its why "contentoptions" doeswork now.. ¿Have another way to implement?

tkx 4 the answers

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
I resolve this making another component whit my app container inside and put the provider outside

```js
const Aplicacion = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: DrawerStack,
      Login: Loginstack
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
    }
  )
);export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(Reducers)}>
        <Aplicacion/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```